# Error in Model with caret Package

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, cross-validation

I am running the following code with data traing with targetBuy as response 
variable

```
# load the library
library(caret)
library(klaR)

# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
model <- train(TargetBuy ~ ., data = traing, trControl = train_control, method = "nb")
print(model)
```

Getting the following error

> Error in train(TargetBuy ~ ., data = traing, trControl =
>   train_control,  :     unused arguments (data = traing, trControl =
>   train_control, method = "nb")

Answer (score 1):

Please read carefully `caret::train` since S3 method for class `formula` is slightly different than default S3 method for `caret::train` (and takes different arguments)

This should do the work:

```
model <- caret::train(y = traing$TargetBuy, x = traing[, colnames(traing) != 'TargetBuy'], trControl = train_control, method = "nb")
```

You can also use `model.matrix`, but then you need to remember that it removes missing values. See [this post for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616210/model-matrix-with-na-action-null):

```
model <- caret::train(y = factor(traing$TargetBuy), x = model.matrix(TargetBuy ~ ., data = traing), trControl = train_control, method = "nb")
```

Comment: Tried it getting following error                                                                              
 unused arguments (y = factor(traing$TargetBuy), x = model.matrix(TargetBuy ~ ., data = traing), trControl = train_control, method = "nb")

Comment: try specifying the package you are using explicitly - `caret::train`. Also notice that it works with build-in dataset: model <- train(y = factor(mtcars$vs), x = model.matrix(vs ~ ., data = mtcars), trControl = train_control, method = "nb")

Comment: Please see how I edited the answer. I have changed `train` to `caret::train` in the query.
For more reference see `?'::'` in R

Comment: Working but getting new error       Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

Comment: It seems like you had some missing values in your dataset. I have modified my answer.